# Audio Capacitor Values

Tags: capacitor, audio, analog

I'm looking to stock my capacitor drawers and I was just looking through trying to find standard values or some kind of list for them and I couldn't find a really good list of standard values for audio applications and other analog circuits.

I'm looking for polypropylene capacitors (these seem to be the best bang for my buck when it comes to audio) rated for at least 100 V (I work with 60 V-80 V AC signals sometimes) to be used for bypass and decoupling (and filters).

What values should I get to really cover all the bases?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

10 22 33 47 68 series is pretty much all you will need. For audio/analog applications you will probably need values from 10p–1μ PP and 1μ–470μ electrolytic and some bigger ~10000μF caps.